# Display a Excel Chart

Tags: web-part, excel

I'm using sharepoint for my team, and i would like to dispalay charts which update daily from my data connections. Currently i use a images and update daily, i want to automate this by hosing the spreadsheet on the sharepoint page.

What would be the best way to do this? I'm familular with Sharepoint 2007 but not 2010, so i want looking for a excel webpart to add, but could not find anything like this in 2010.

Comment: Does your SharePoint edition include Excel Services?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Excel REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ee556820(v=office.15).aspx) to set current values to parameter cells in the spreadsheet and retrieve an updated chart without modifying the workbook: `http://<ServerName>/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Docs/Documents/sampleWorkbook.xlsx/model/Charts('Chart 1')?Ranges('Sheet1!A1')=5.5`